# Property does not exist on type in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an ionic 4 crud and in my `create.page.ts` I'm validating the forms, however I was trying to use the async method and await to use `this.loading.ctrl`, but I am getting this error described on the title.

Also when I try handling its return, I also get an error on `this.router.navigateByUrl('');` In case it isn't clear exactly what is going on here, here's my `create.page.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/data/firestore.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.page.scss'],
})
export class CreatePage implements OnInit {
  public createConsultaForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public firestoreService: FirestoreService, formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    loadingCtrl: LoadingController, alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
      this.createConsultaForm = formBuilder.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required],
        unidade: ['', Validators.required],
        medNome: ['', Validators.required],
        especialidade: ['', Validators.required],
        endereco: ['', Validators.required],
        data: ['', Validators.required],
        hora: ['', Validators.required],
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async createConsulta() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    const id = this.createConsultaForm.value.id;
    const unidade = this.createConsultaForm.value.unidade;
    const medNome = this.createConsultaForm.value.medNome;
    const especialidade = this.createConsultaForm.value.especialidade;
    const endereco = this.createConsultaForm.value.endereco;
    const data = this.createConsultaForm.value.data;
    const hora = this.createConsultaForm.value.hora;

    this.firestoreService
      .createConsulta(unidade, especialidade, medNome,  endereco, data, hora)
      .then(
        () => {
          loading.dismiss().then(() => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('');
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );

    return await loading.present();
  }
}
```

On this line:

```
const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
```

I get:

> Property 'loadingCtrl' does not exist on type 'CreatePage'

and on this line:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('');
```

I get

> Property 'router' does not exist on type 'CreatePage'

Comment: Can you give the full error please? Which property does not exist? Which line is the error on?

Comment: I have edited my post to display more visibly the errors

Comment: somebody just posted the solution, but they deleted their answer lol

Comment: @AJT_82, there is, because im using it as type angular from when i generated the project via CLI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont see anywhere you import `Router`

Import `Router` and instantiate inside the constructor

```
constructor(router: Router) { this.router.navigateByUrl(...); }
```

Comment: Exactly! I forgot to add it to my constructor, also declare public the loading controller, thanks!

Comment: I stand corrected, well haven't worked with v4 so that is my excuse :P

Comment: Great! I was confused too with AJT's comment. Upvote if that helped